# Pass Pins values to next page

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I am using map in my app and added some pins to it.

When I click on pin it display some info.

Now I want to pass the values/info of pins to next page after clicking on pin tooltip.

Here is what I am trying:

```
Pin pins;
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            // workerListVM.DisplayMap();
            var employeesDetail = await workerListVM.getdetail();
            foreach (var employees in employeesDetail)
            {
                try
                {
                    map1.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(employees.Latitude, employees.Longitude),Distance.FromMiles(.5)));
                    var position = new Position(employees.Latitude, employees.Longitude);

                     pins = new Pin()
                    {
                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Position = position,
                        Label = employees.UserName,
                        Address = employees.City
                    };
                    map1.Pins.Add(pins);
                    pins.Clicked += Pins_Clicked;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException) { }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }

        private void Pins_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert($"{pins.Label}", $"{pins.Address}", "Ok");
        }
```

But its not working.

Comment: please define "not working".  Is it crashing?  Do you get an error or exception?  What specifically is wrong?

Comment: thanks for your response but right now i found the solution.

Comment: @muhammad-zubair If finding the solution, please remember to post it as answer.